# Stopping a Servlet from returning a Response

Tags: java, validation, servlets, error-handling, response

Had a look through SO and couldn't find a question similar to what I'm after. I'll start off by explaining what I'm trying to do, then finish up with a more specific question..

**My aim**

I have a link that passes a query string parameter to my servlet. That parameter is `report`. If `report = true` in the servlet, then I'll generate a PDF document. The PDF document then returns this value, by setting the response's `mime type` to `application/pdf`. This code is shown below:

```
        String mimeType = "application/pdf";
        res.setContentType(mimeType);
        res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" +    
        getEventID(doc) + ".pdf\"");
        // Set the response content type and pdf attachment.

        out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        // All PDF Data is pushed onto the output stream.
        com.lowagie.text.Document pdfDoc = buildPDF(getEventID(doc));
```

This code is then written to the `response` object's output stream.

```
        if(pdfDoc == null)
        {
            // Something went wrong in generating the report.
            return false;
        }
        // Create the PDF document.
        out.writeTo(res.getOutputStream());
```

If all goes well, the class returns `true`. If not, it returns `false`. Now, the problem I'm having is if it returns false. Essentially, I want to point blank stop the data from going anywhere. I added the check to make sure things went well, *before* I write anything to the output stream, so at the moment what I have is a response that is set to PDF type, but contains no data, if something goes wrong that is.

Next, I have a function that will test the output of the class. If it's true, then all is good, but if it is false, then it sets an `error` parameter:

```
 if(!PdfReportGenerator.generateReport(res, repositoryURI)) {
             req.getSession().setAttribute(SDRestServlet.PDF_ERROR, "error");
             // This will then re-direct back to the current URL, meaning the page
             // looks like it doesn't do anything.
             res.sendRedirect(req.getRequestURI());
 }
```

The problem is, this re-directing is really not helping at all. It's messing up other values that are stored in the `request` and, while it's making the page appear like it's doing nothing, it doesn't allow me to output an error message to the user.

**The issue**

While I know how to *make it seem like* the web response is not returning, it means that I can not output any meaningful information to the user, which is obviously not the ideal outcome.

**My question**

Is there a way to force the servlet to stop, or return something so that the browser ignores the data?

My second question is, if there is something I can send back to the browser, is there anything I can do on the client side to cause a message to pop up (can be as simple as `alert()`)?

I've been as clear as I possibly can be, so if there's anything you need to know, just ask :)

Comment: Why would you even set the mime type to PDF before you know whether you're returning a PDF or an error?

Comment: When I started writing this I didn't really know what I was doing, so I was just going from the other code I saw in this project. I know that isn't exactly best practise, but can we focus on the question first, and then I'll act on your improvement suggestions?

Comment: That wasn't an improvement suggestion. I would set the mime-type after I know whether I'm returning a PDF or an error message. Or rather I wouldn't set the mime-type at all, if I'm redirecting to an error page.

Comment: Agreed, but I don't want to re-direct to an error page. I would much rather an error message appeared on the client side without the need for a page move.

Comment: Then you'll need to either re-render the original page and show an error message, or use ajax.

Comment: The solution I went with was: If there is no error, set the mime type etc. IF there was an error, then don't set the mime-type. Obviously, your suggestion influenced the decision. Then I changed the XSLT files to reflect an error message if a request attribute was set. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to force the servlet to stop, or return something so
>   that the browser ignores the data?

Please try setting zero response using method "ServletResponse.setContentLength(int)"

> My second question is, if there is something I can send back to the
>   browser, is there anything I can do on the client side to cause a
>   message to pop up (can be as simple as alert())?

Yes you can but you need to update back header to say "text/html" and set all the variable as you would do in a normal scenario of a server request

SECOND APPROACH:

If I have to build it from scratch, would following following approach:

1. First make and AJAX call to find whether pdf need to be generated or not
2. If response is false show error message.
3. If response is true send request to server to generate PDF

Hopefully I was able to help you a bit here.